# Select most recent date + inner join

Tags: sql

I am trying query for the most recent scan date (the two most recent ones are 3/5/2012 and 3/1/2012 ... I'd like to only return records from 3/5/2012, but I need this to be automated so every time a new scan is run the query is only pulling the most recent date.

I'm also joining the two tables by IP. I put together the query below and am receiving the error "Please check the SQL syntax. Column `qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanName` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

```
SELECT qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanName,
    qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.pspplMSSeverity,
    qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.smachIPAddress,
    qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate.PatchMissing, 
    MAX(qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanDate)
FROM qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate
INNER JOIN qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate
ON qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.smachIPAddress=qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate.smachIPAddress
WHERE qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanName LIKE '%mgmt%' 
    AND qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanDate>= dateadd(day,-30,getdate())
ORDER BY qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanDate DESC
```

Edit: Here is some sample data of what is being returned:

```
Column1 smachIPAddress   ScanName   pspplMSSeverity PatchMissing

3/5/2012 15:24  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   1
3/5/2012 15:24  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   1
3/5/2012 15:24  1162.1.1.1  Mgmt Servers OU 0   1
3/5/2012 15:24  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   2
3/5/2012 15:24  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   1
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   2
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   4
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   2
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   3
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   1
3/1/2012 17:29  162.1.1.1   Mgmt Servers OU 0   3
```

First table:

```
table_name  ordinal_position    column_name data_type   is_nullable character_maximum_length
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 1   MachineGroup    nvarchar    YES 276
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 2   ScanID  int NO  
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 3   ScanUser    nvarchar    YES 4000
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 4   ScanDate    datetime    NO  
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 5   ScanName    nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 6   itemType    int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 7   smachID int NO  
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 8   smachName   nvarchar    NO  255
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 9   smachIPAddress  nvarchar    YES 39
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 10  smachDomainName nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 11  smachIPDecimal  float   YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 12  smachAnnotation ntext   YES 1073741823
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 13  smachNotFoundReasonErrorNum smallint    YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 14  smachServerType int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 15  mmOSID  int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 16  patchBulletinID nvarchar    NO  255
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 17  patchBulletinURL    nvarchar    YES 4000
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 18  patchQNumbers   nvarchar    NO  255
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 19  patchLevel  int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 20  pspplMSSeverity int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 21  pspplCriticality    int YES 
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 22  pspplAnnotation nvarchar    YES 4000
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 23  prodID  int NO  
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 24  spplspID    int NO  
qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate 25  scanType    int YES
```

2nd table:

```
table_name  ordinal_position    column_name data_type   is_nullable character_maximum_length
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   1   ScanID  int NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   2   scanType    int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   3   ScanName    nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   4   ScanDate    datetime    NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   5   ScanUser    nvarchar    YES 4000
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   6   consoleID   int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   7   consoleName nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   8   smachName   nvarchar    NO  255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   9   smachIPAddress  nvarchar    YES 39
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   10  scantName   nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   11  FirstPatchGroupName nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   12  CountPatchGroups    int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   13  smachAgent  smallint    NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   14  smachDomainName nvarchar    YES 255
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   15  smachIPDecimal  float   YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   16  smachID int NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   17  smachListType   int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   18  ScanXMLVersion  nvarchar    YES 50
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   19  ScanXMLDate datetime    YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   20  itemLanguageID  nvarchar    YES 4
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   21  PatchFoundOrInstalled   int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   22  PatchMissing    int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   23  ServicePackMissing  int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   24  CountofMachinesScanned  int NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   25  CountofMachinesNotScanned   int NO  
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   26  TotalMachines   int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   27  ScanFoundPatches    int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   28  ScanMissingPatches  int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   29  ScanServicePackMissing  int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   30  CountOfGroups   int YES 
qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate   31  grpName nvarchar    YES 255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is telling you the problem, if you are using an `Aggregate` function `MAX()`, `SUM()`, etc the fields not using the Aggregate must be included in a `GROUP BY`.

Below is what your query looks like with aliases and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CPA.ScanName,
    CPA.pspplMSSeverity,
    CPA.smachIPAddress,
    SDA.PatchMissing, 
    MAX(CPA.ScanDate)
FROM qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate CPA
INNER JOIN qryReportsScanSummaryWithDetailsAggregate SDA
    ON CPA.smachIPAddress=SDA.smachIPAddress
WHERE CPA.ScanName LIKE '%mgmt%' 
    AND CPA.ScanDate>= dateadd(day,-30,getdate())
GROUP BY CPA.ScanName, CPA.pspplMSSeverity, CPA.smachIPAddress
    , SDA.PatchMissing, CPA.ScanDate
ORDER BY CPA.ScanDate DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ran this and received the error: "Please check the SQL syntax. Column "qryReportsCondensedPatchesAggregate.ScanDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Then that means that you need to add it to the GROUP BY clause as well. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it displays now. However I am not getting the most recent date of 3/5/2012. I am also getting 3/1/2012 still. Am I on the wrong track using the MAX aggregate function for this?

Comment: I added in some sample data, just had to block out the ips

Comment: What is your expected result with the query?

Comment: I would like only the most recent scan date (3/5/2012) but would like to ensure that the query only returns the most recent dates every time a new scan in run and does not return any other dates.

Comment: the most recent scan for each IP address?

Comment: Just the most recent scan date, because the IPs are grouped and scanned at different times

Comment: Can you post the table structures of both tables you are joining on?